# How to fix an index.html overriding all other HTML pages of a website

Tags: html, indexing, meta

I have added the metadata and title for each page. However, all pages appear with the index.html title and metadata.

I have analyzed the website with different audit tool and site map generators, and they all can only find one page: the index.html (homepage).

It looks like the index is overriding all others pages. How can I fix it?

The robots.txt does not seem to be the issue here
The website is built on ruby on rails

I expect that the title of each page can be displayed in the browser, instead of all showing the title of index.html.

Comment: Are you sure that the index.html is used there? Did you make the Ruby project? If not, maybe Ruby generated the HTML code for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have not made the Ruby project. Could you please help me to figure out which actions should I take? Many thanks!